Why fetch json parsing is slower when the browser network is slowed down?
I was running some profiling on a simple browser fetch call and noticed something curious.
I'll paste here an example code:
    const t0 = performance.now();
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/data');
    const t1 = performance.now();
    await response.json();
    const t2 = performance.now();
    const res1 = `${t1 - t0}ms`;
    const res2 = `${t2 - t1}ms`;

When I slow down the network from the Chrome devTools (or any chromium based ), I see see res1 increasing and res2 staying the same.
When I do the same in Firefox, besides seeing way smaller timings, but I also see res2 increasing and res1 staying the same, which is unexpected.
Do they have a different implementation?
Why there is this difference in behaviour?
What are the two awaits waiting, exactly? await fetch() is waiting for the whole response or only the headers? Because it seems different depending on browsers.
Maybe this is related to how firefox devTools slow down the network?
P.S. I guess this question can be an extension of this one: Is `Body.json()` faster than `JSON.parse(responseText)` for JSON received from `fetch`?

I'd bet that it has more to do with how Firefox simulates network congestion. If you ever find a way to impede network performance outside your machine (in a way that your coworkers and/or family are willing to indulge), that would give you the answer.
